# Meromorphic functions on a Riemann surface as quotient of polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Consider a compact Riemann surface $C$ embedded in a projective plane with coordinates $[x:y:z]$.
Is it possible to write any meromorphic function $f\in M(C)$ as a fraction $f=\frac{P(x,y,z)}{Q(x,y,z)}$ with $P,Q$ homogeneous polynomials of the same degree having no common zero on $C$?
Of course $Q(x,y,z)$ will have zeroes on $C$ since a (non constant) meromorphic function on $C$ can not be holomorphic everywhere, but I'm asking whether at such zeroes $P$ will be non-zero.
I am pretty sure that Riemann-Roch guarantees that the answer is yes provided the common degree of $P$ and $Q$ is large enough, but I'd be grateful for a clean write-up.

Comment: How many zeros does a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$ have on $zy^2=x^3+xz^2$ ? Then note that $x/z$ has only two zeros and two poles

Comment: Avoid this kind of unfriendly behavior. Bezout's theorem says that $P$ has $3\deg(P)$ zeros on the smooth projective curve $zy^2=x^3+xz^2$. So any meromorphic function not having 3n zeros and poles doesn't have any chance to be of the form you asked.

Comment: Every meromorphic function is a quotient of two homogeneous polynomials but not all are such that $P,Q$ have no **common zero** which is your question. Once again $P$ has $3\deg(P)$ zeros so if $P,Q$ have no common zeros (and $\deg(P)=\deg(Q)$ then $P/Q$ is a meromorphic function with $3\deg(P)$ zeros and $3\deg(P)$ poles.

Comment: I gave one in the first comment, $x/z$ on the degree 3 smooth complex projective curve (elliptic curve) $zy^2=x^3+xz^2$. It is a quotient of two homogeneous polynomials but they'll always have a common zero (here at $[0:1:0]$). I don't think that Nicolas Hemelsoet noticed the "no common zero" point.

Comment: @reuns: Sorry, I had forgotten about your example. I'll think about it and meanwhile I have deleted my unfair comments.

Comment: I have a 3 lines proof for an elliptic curve if you want (including a proof of Bezout)

Comment: @reuns I would encourage you to sum up your comments concerning the elliptic curve counterexample in an answer which I (and hopefully other users) would then upvote. This would be neater than this long string of comments for which my initial skepticism is responsible. (I have deleted all my previous comments now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often no, by Bezout's theorem.

Let $$E:zy^2=x^3+z^3\subset \Bbb{P^2(C)}$$

- For an homogeneous polynomial $f\in \Bbb{C}[x,y,z]$ of degree $d$ its zeros on $E$ are well defined, to define their multiplicities: take $w\in \{x,y,z\}$ not vanishing at $P$ and look at the order at $P$ of the zero of the meromorphic function $f/w^d$.
- $x$ has 3 simple zeros at $[0:1:1],[0:-1:1],[0:1:0]$
- $x^d$ has $3d$ zeros
- $f/x^d$ is a meromorphic function, **with the same number of zeros and poles**, so $f$ must have $3d$ zeros.
- The meromorphic function $x/z$ has two simple zeros at $[0:1:1],[0:-1:1]$ and a double pole at $[0:1:0]$.

It can't be that $$x/z=f/g$$ with $f,g$ homogeneous of same degree $d$ and **with no common zero**, as $f/g$ would have $3d$ zeros and poles whereas $x/z$ has $2$ zeros and poles.

Comment: Congratulations on this perfect answer, which I of course "accept" (in the technical sense of this site: green check mark!) and upvote. Thanks a lot.